# Exclude record from rails loop - Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I am using the [related products gem](https://github.com/paul-at/spree_product_line) and have modified it slightly but I have 1 bug that I cant figure out.

Basically the get method uses the searcher class to find all the taxonomies and displays 6 products that are in the same category, in my view I am just displaying the first 1 category as some products have multiple categories.

My problem is, in a migration I create a taxonomy called 'Tags' and the a child taxon called 'Featured' (products that display on the home page) then destroy the parent taxonomy so it doesn't appear on the customer facing website. For all products tagged with the Featured taxon throws an undefined method for 'is_product_line' error. All other products not tagged with the Featured taxon works perfectly.

I need a way to exclude this taxon when the get method builds the categories in the controller. I have added it to the method but not sure how to exclude it from the @categores <<{ }

### Controller

```
module Spree
  class RelatedProductsController < Spree::StoreController
  @@display_related_items = 6

  def get
    product = Product.order("name ASC").find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink])
    ### Featured is taxonmony without a parent taxon
    featured = Spree::Taxon.where(:name => 'Featured')
    @categories = []
    product.taxons.each do |taxon|
      if taxon.taxonomy.is_product_line
        @categories << {
          :taxon => taxon,
          :searcher => build_searcher({ :taxon => taxon.id, :per_page => @@display_related_items })
        }
      end
    end
    render layout: false
    end
  end
end
```

#### Get.html.erb

```
<% @categories.first(1).each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category[:taxon].pretty_name, spree.nested_taxons_path(category[:taxon].permalink) %>
  <%= render :partial => 'products', :locals => { :products => category[:searcher].retrieve_products, :taxon => category[:taxon] } %>
<% end %>
```

#### _product.html.erb

```
<% if products.any? %>
  <% products.each do |product| %>
  <div id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="columns large-2" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="product-image">
      <%= link_to product_image(product, :itemprop => "image"), product, :itemprop => 'url' %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to truncate(product.name, :length => 50), product, :class => 'info', :itemprop => "name", :title => product.name %>
    <p class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= display_price(product) %></p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to just reject your featured taxon from the product.taxons e.g.

```
product.taxons.reject{|t| t.name == 'Featured'}.each do |taxon|
```